# making simple blog reply quotes with php

Tags: php

I've been struggling with this for hours

I need to convert this string

```
"> example quote /n"
```

to this

```
<blockquote> example quote /n </blockquote>
```

so if I have a more than one quote ">" like this

```
">> example quote /n"
```

it would look like this

```
< blockquote>< blockquote>example quote < /blockquote >< /blockquote > <br>
```

another example would be:

">>this is a great string /n > next quote"

```
< blockquote>< blockquote> this is a great string < /blockquote >< /blockquote > <br>
< blockquote> next quote < /blockquote >
```

This is my code so far

```
            // plain comment
            $text = "> we are here /n";

            // explode into array
            $single_quotes = explode("/n", $text);

            $renderedHtml = "";
            $quoteopeners = "";
            $quoteclosers = "";

            //make blockquote out of it
            foreach($single_quotes as $quote)
            {
                $number_of_quotes = substr_count($quote,'>');

                for($i = 0; $i < $number_of_quotes; $i++)
                {
                   $quoteopeners.= '<blockquote>';
                   $quoteclosers.='</blockquote>';
                }

                //replace all the '>' with spaces
                $quote = str_replace('>','', $quote);
                $quote = str_replace('/n','', $quote);

                $renderedHtml.= $quoteopeners.$quote.$quoteclosers;
            }
```

For some reason when I type 
"> we are here /n "

it renders these random quotes at the end

```
<blockquote> we are here </blockquote><blockquote></blockquote>
```

If you had a complete new solution to this problem it would be fine too

Comment: Perhaps this may help later? https://eval.in/188423

Answer (score 1):

$quoteopeners and $quoteclosers are not initialized the right place. Try this :

```
<?php
 // plain comment
    $text = ">> we are here /n";

    // explode into array
    $single_quotes = explode("/n", $text);

    $renderedHtml = "";

    //make blockquote out of it
    foreach($single_quotes as $quote)
    {
        $number_of_quotes = substr_count($quote,'>');

        $quoteopeners = "";
        $quoteclosers = "";

        for($i = 0; $i < $number_of_quotes; $i++)
        {
           $quoteopeners.= '<blockquote>';
           $quoteclosers.='</blockquote>';
        }

        //replace all the '>' with spaces
        $quote = str_replace('>','', $quote);
        $quote = str_replace('/n','', $quote);

        $renderedHtml.= $quoteopeners.$quote.$quoteclosers;
    }

    echo $renderedHtml;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) for this

```
<?php

 $str = preg_replace_callback(
            '/^(\>+) (\w+(\s+\w+)*)/',
            function ($matches) {
                return str_repeat("<blockquote>", strlen($matches[1])) . $matches[2] . str_repeat("</blockquote>", strlen($matches[1]));
            }, $string);
    echo $str;
```

For example;

```
//Output: <blockquote>This is a simple quote</blockquote>
$string = "> This is a simple quote";

//Output: <blockquote><blockquote>This is a simple quote</blockquote></blockquote>
$string = ">> This is a simple quote";
```

#### [Live Preview](https://eval.in/188459)

**Useful sites**

- http://www.phpliveregex.com/
- http://www.regexr.com/